# Is there a way to get the bitrate in Twilio for Android?

Tags: android, twilio

Is there a way to get the bit-rate in `Twilio`?
I noticed that the Room object gets you the state and the state gets you the bytes send and received, but it only shows it once when you queried it in the `onConnected` callback and I couldn't find a way to get data in any other `Twilio` callback or Android callback. I also couldn't find a way to observe the `getState` from the Room object.

Does anyone knows a way to get the bit-rate in `Twilio`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Apologies, I'm not an Android developer, but this is what I believe you need.

Rather than calling on the room state, you should call [`getStats` on the room](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-video-android/docs/latest/com/twilio/video/Room.html#getStats-com.twilio.video.StatsListener-) and pass it an implementation of a [`StatsListener`](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-video-android/docs/latest/com/twilio/video/StatsListener.html). That way the room will asynchronously report the stats of all the associated tracks. I can't be sure whether it will keep observing the stats, or whether you could just keep calling to `getStats` when you get a result, passing the same listener again.

Take a look and let me know how it goes.